Filter the table with Arrayformula in the first row
I would like to apply filters to columns A - O. If I now sort column I, for example, the formulas that are used in the columns are also sorted. Is it possible to place the formulas outside the columns so that they are not rearranged? Screenshot 1 shows the table after entering the values in columns E7:E - O7:O. Screenshot 2 shows the table after sorting. Is it possible to write the formula in Apps script and will this solve the problem. Furthermore, I don't want to have empty rows after deleting the content from cells. When I delete the contents e.g. from cells A7 - H7. In column P7 -P I would like to place buttons to delete the respective column. I need a little help to write the script.
Cell I7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($F7:F);IF(ISBLANK($G7:G);"";ROUND(($H7:H-$G7:G)*10000;2));ROUND(($F7:F-$H7:H)*10000;2)))

Cell J7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($E7:E);"";ROUND(($E7:E)*$O$2/1000;2)))

Cell K7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($F7:F);IF(ISBLANK($G7:G);"";ROUND(($N$2-$G7:G)*$E7:E/$G7:G*(-1);2));ROUND(($N$2-$F7:F)*$E7:E/$F7:F*(-1);2)))

Cell L7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($E7:E);"";ROUND(($J7:J)+($K7:K);2)))

Cell M7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($E7:E);"";SCAN($A$2;$L7:L;LAMBDA(a;r;a+r))))

Cell N7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($E7:E);"";ROUND(($L7:L/$M7:M*100);2)))

Cell O7
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($G7:G);IF(ISBLANK($F7:F);"";ROUND($E7:E*$I7:I*0,0001/$F7:F;2));ROUND($E7:E*$I7:I*0,0001/$G7:G;2)))




put the formulas in the header using VSTACK or array literal.

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

The Arrayformula into the header solves this problem.
={"Cellname";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($F7:F);IF(ISBLANK($G7:G);"";ROUND(($H7:H-$G7:G)*10000;2));ROUND(($F7:F-$H7:H)*10000;2)))}

